# Column order in stacked bar chart is the the opposite from spreadheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Often I have a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc like this:

```
Apple 423412 124233 
Banana 234234 23434
Cherry 23324 423432
```

I then make a stacked bar chart. However the order of the stacked bar chart is always the other way around, from top to bottom: Cherry, Banana, Apple. However I want the order to be the same as in the spreadsheet itself: Apple, Banana, Cherry. (Funnily I have the same issue when I use Excel instead of Calc). How can I achieve this?

--
I am using LibreOffice Calc Version 3.6.2.2 (Build ID: 360m1(Build:2)) under Xubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on the y axis line itself, you can get a selector at both ends of the y axis. (This is frustratingly difficult, as you often end up selecting the chart, or one of the ranges, or something else).

Once you have selected the y axis, you can right-click and choose "Format Axis..."

On the 'Scale' tab, check the "Reverse direction" check box.

I have no idea why it is initially backward though.

Comment: GregHNZ, you mean the X axis, not the Y axis, right?

Comment: Hey, look at that, LibreOffice calls the axis that goes up and down the "X axis", how singular. I meant the axis that you wish to change the order of.

Comment: Yes - I'd find terminology "independent variable" and "dependent variable" more precise and unambiguous with the layout of a bar chart - but i suppose everyone is accustomed to "X" & "Y".

Comment: The axis is in the correct orientation (0 to max) but the data is evaluated top to bottom and the chart is filled bottom to top. This is logical but I want the data to be stacked top to bottom so I want it to be evaluated bottom to top.